# JPA saving foreign key with Null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got a 2 entity classes that the primary key for the entity is part of a composite key for the other.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "objectone")
public class ObjectOne {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  private UUID id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "objectOneId", updatable = false)
  Set<ObjectTwo> ObjectTwoList;
```

Here is the entity class for object with the composite key

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "objecttwo")
@IdClass(ObjectTwoKey.class)
public class ObjectTwo {
  @Id
  @NotNull
  private UUID objectOneId;
  @Id
  @NotNull
  private UUID triggerWorkOrderId;
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "status")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Status status;

<-- other fields ommitted ->
}
```

If I build a ObjectOne object I also add objectTwo as a set:

```
    objectOne.setObjectTwoList(Collections.singleton(objectTwo));

    ObjectOne save = repo.save(objectOne);
```

`save` would contain the Set of objectTwo, but the foreign key (objectOneId) is set to null, so when I try to retrieve it using `repo.findById`, i'll only get objectOne but objectTwo is not in the list. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `objectTwo` is probably not saved yet and you're not cascading saves etc. to `ObjectTwoList` to it won't be saved. Also note that if the "objecttwo" table holds the foreign key you need to get it there, i.e. set `objectTwo.objectOneId` before saving (read up on "owing side of a relation").